# What are $\mathcal{F}_g$ in string theory?

Tags: string-theory, definition, topology, partition-function, topological-field-theory

I was reading an article and came up on $\mathcal{F}_g$. Namely, it was in the following equation, $$\psi_{top} = \exp(\sum_g \mathcal{F}_g)$$ where I believe the $g$ denotes the genus of the topology of the string, but I **think** that $\mathcal{F}_g$ refers to the corrections to the string, in this case the string wave-function which would make sense since we really only need to care about the genus, and then the corrections relate the Euler-characteristic.

Just wanted to make sure I was correct and was not mixing up any terminology, thanks.

The paper: [Baby Universes in String Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0504221) equation 1.1, footnote 1 as well. I know I am missing some details since to simply have the two relate, it requires some stuff from cohomology to make the relation, but I just need the overall understanding (to give physical reasoning).

Comment: I wouldn't call it an "F-term" because that means something completely unrelated in supersymmetry. $F_g$ is commonly called the **genus-g free energy**. It also doesn't have anything to do with "corrections to the string wavefunction" either - $\psi$ here is the *partition function*.

Comment: @NiharKarve That appears to be an answer, not a comment ;)

Comment: @Cassem02 A wonderful reference to clarify this, is the page 26 of  [Topological strings and their physical applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0410178).